# How to combine df.loc with for-loop to calculate new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to learn how to use df.loc and for-loop to calculate new columns for the dataframe below
Problem: from df_G, for T = 400, take value of each Go_j as input
Then add new column "G_ads_400" in dataframe df = df['Adsorption_energy_eV'] - Go_h2o

[df_G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYlbv.png)

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDrzk.png)

here is my code for each Temperature

```
Go_co2 = df_G.loc[df_G.index == "400" & df_G.Go_CO2]
Go_o2= df_G.loc[df_G.index == "400" & df_G.Go_O2]
Go_co= df_G.loc[df_G.index == "400" & df_G.Go_CO]

df.loc[df['Adsorbates'] == "CO2", "G_ads_400"] = df.Adsorption_energy_eV-Go_co2
df.loc[df['Adsorbates'] == "CO", "G_ads_400"] = df.Adsorption_energy_eV-Go_co
df.loc[df['Adsorbates'] == "O2", "G_ads_400"] = df.Adsorption_energy_eV-Go_o2
```

I am not sure why I kept having error and I would like to know how to put it in a for-loop so it looks less messy

Comment: dont share links or pics. share actual data. for ur task, i bliv u can do it without for loops and just work within pandas/numpy

Comment: Hello - welcome to stack overflow! If you're running into an error, please post the [traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) so we can understand where your code is failing. Please see [this post on how to ask a well recieved question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some best practices.